# Magento mega menu extension install giving error

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.4, magento-1.6

magento mega menu extension problem

using this http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/wp_custom_menu extension

getting error 
CONNECT ERROR: Unsupported resource type

Comment: Can u plz describe the error??

Comment: I'm try to install mega menu in magento for my site using above link extension. When i click install in console 'checking dependencies of packages CONNECT ERROR: Unsupported resource type'